# Is there a non-right triangle whose circumcenter lies on one of its sides?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Here is one elementary, yet interesting geometric question.

If we have a right triangle, its circumcenter is the midpoint of its hypotenuse.

How to prove other direction? Namely,

> Is there a non-right triangle which corresponding circumcenter is lying on one of its sides?

Comment: No, by the [Theorem of Thales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem#:~:text=In%20geometry%2C%20Thales's%20theorem%20states,ABC%20is%20a%20right%20angle.)

Comment: No, the side with the circumcenter would be a diameter of the circle. Then the third vertex of the triangle (the one that isn't an endpoint of the diameter) would necessarily be a right angle, to subtend an arc of 180 degrees.

Comment: Circumcenter location can be used to classify triangles. If it is on a side, the triangle has a right angle. If it is outside the triangle, the triangle has an obtuse angle. If it is inside the triangle, the triangle has all acute angles.

Comment: Thanks, but I am interested in rigorous and detailed geometric proof

Comment: This is literally the Theorem of Thales.  The Wiki article I linked to contains three proofs.

Comment: Okay this indeed is Theorem of Tales, but a bit disguised. Thanks